The Thread join() method does not work properly in a GUI program
I have a parser with GUI written in Kivy. The main body of the parser is the market_parse function. I need the deactivate_widgets function to be triggered before executing the thread, and after activate_widgets function. However, this is not happening. If you remove the thread.join(), then both functions are triggered, and activate_widgets is triggered immediately after launching market_parse. If you leave the thread.join(), then deactivate_widgets does not have time to work.
My kv-file
FloatLayout:
    adaptive_size: True
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 42/255, 46/255, 53/255, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    MDTextField:
        id: input_field
        mode: "outlined"
        size_hint: .85, None
        adaptive_size: True
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        MDTextFieldHintText:
            text: "Name"

    MDButton:
        id: search_button
        style: "filled"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .35}
        radius: 10
        adaptive_size: True
        disabled: False
        on_press:
            app.button_press()
        MDButtonIcon:
            icon: "magnify"
        MDButtonText:
            text: "Price"
            bold: True

    MDCircularProgressIndicator:
        id: load_indicator
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "24dp", "24dp"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .35}
        opacity: 0

    MDLinearProgressIndicator:
        id: progress_indicator
        opacity: 0
        size_hint: .8, None
        type: "determinate"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .25}
        value: 0
        indicator_color: 'mediumpurple'

My py-file:
class ParserApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        MDApp.title = "Parser"
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Lightslategrey"
        Window.size = (400, 500)
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def button_press(self):        
        progress_indicator = self.root.ids.progress_indicator       
        user_input_value = self.root.ids.input_field.text.strip()
        if user_input_value != '':
            self.deactivate_widgets()
            thread = Thread(target=market_parse, args=(user_input_value, progress_indicator))
            try:
                thread.start()
                thread.join()
            except:
                thread.join()
            self.activate_widgets()

    def deactivate_widgets(self):
        self.root.ids.search_button.disabled = True
        self.root.ids.input_field.disabled = True        
        self.root.ids.search_button.opacity = 0
        self.root.ids.load_indicator.opacity = 1
        self.root.ids.progress_indicator.opacity = 1

    def activate_widgets(self):
        self.root.ids.search_button.disabled = False
        self.root.ids.input_field.disabled = False        
        self.root.ids.search_button.opacity = 1
        self.root.ids.load_indicator.opacity = 0
        self.root.ids.progress_indicator.opacity = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ParserApp().run()

What I do wrong?

Starting a thread and then immediately joining it doesn't make sense. Instead, you could just call the code it calls directly. Point is, you don't get any concurrency if you start and join the thread from the same button handler. Instead, you start it there and from the thread, you emit an event once it is finished which re-enables the widget.

Also note, except: thread.join() makes no sense either. join is not a "cleanup" operation. In fact, thread.join() does not do anything at all to thread. If thread has been started, then thread.join() does nothing except wait for thread to finish. And if thread failed to start, which is the only way your code can ever reach the second thread.join() call, then thread.join() will raise a run-time error.
